# Batch insert heading/newline to ASCII file if value of column changes

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed

I have a file similar to this:

```
A B C
D E C
F G C
A B X
F G X
A B Q
D E Q
```

Thats what I am looking for

```
> C
A B C
D E C
F G C
> X
A B X
F G X
> Q
A B Q
D E Q
```

So far I have a kind of complicated work-around.
Using AWK to add a empty line.

```
awk -v i=3 "NR>0 && $i!=p { print "A" }{ p=$i } 1" file.txt
```

I dont manage to add a ">" directly with awk since its a newline value. Instead of the "A", awk is outputting a empty line. Not really sure why..
Using then

```
sed -e "s/^$/>/" file.txt
```

I manage to insert a ">" to the empty line but the heading behind is still missing.

Comment: updated it. the actual data is the same for input and output.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for doing `s/old/new`, **that is all**. What you are attempting to do is not just `s/old/new` so you shouldn't be considering using sed, just use awk:

```
$ awk '$3!=p{print ">", $3; p=$3} 1' file
> C
A B C
D E C
F G C
> X
A B X
F G X
> Q
A B Q
D E Q
```

Comment: As soon as I use print ">" I receive an error "unexpected newline or end of string". The 2nd part of the heading works well. I use cmd on Win7.

Comment: The either a) change the quoting to use Windows quoting rules, or b) save the script in a file and execute it as `awk -f script` or c) install cygwin and call awk from that. Your problem now is the nightmare of Windows quoting rules.

Comment: That's correct, i.e. from `cmd.exe` use `awk "$3!=p{print \"">\"", $3; p=$3} 1" file.txt`

Comment: Or escape the `>` with a caret `^>` like this `gawk "$3!=p{print \"^>\", $3; p=$3} 1" file`

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution. Assuming that your input file is sorted:

```
awk '!a[$NF]++{ print ">",$NF }1' file
```

The output:

```
> C
A B C
D E C
F G C
> X
A B X
F G X
> Q
A B Q
D E Q
```

Comment: In windows a different quoting is necessary `gawk "!a[$NF]++{ print \"^>\",$NF }1" file` +1

Comment: From `cmd.exe` use `awk "!a[$NF]++{ print \"">\"",$NF }1" file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following also and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'NR==1{print ">",$3 RS $0;prev=$3;next} prev!=$3{print ">",$3};1; {prev=$3}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> C
A B C
D E C
F G C
> X
A B X
F G X
> Q
A B Q
D E Q
```